# Remove Empty Line From XML Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-parsing

I am Currently Facing A problem. I am loading a xml file in C# and remove some nodes from it and appending some nodes. now problem is that when i am doing removal from the xml file then there are some empty lines created automatically ,so i want to remove these line .

And when i append some nodes to the parent node in xml then i want the new line in each ending tag

For Eg. My Xml file is

```
<intro id="S0001">
    <title>Introduction Title</title>
     <para>This is a paragraph. Note that paragraphs can contain other block–level objects, such as lists, as well as directly containing text.</para>
     <para>The introduction can contain all of the text objects that a section can contain, except that it cannot be divided into parts, sections and sub–sections.</para>
     <para>The introduction can contain tables:</para>

   </intro><part>
       <no>Part A</no> Article Structure <sup>&lpar;Part Title&rpar;</sup><section1 id="S0002">`enter code here`
     <no>Sect 1</no>
     <title>First Section in Part 1 <sup>&lpar;Section 1 Title&rpar;</sup></title>
     <shortsectionhead>Short Section Header</shortsectionhead>
     <para>This is a section in the first part of the article.</para>
   </section1><section1 id="S0003">
```

Code:

```
XmlNode partNnode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//part");
XmlNode introNode=xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//intro");
XmlDocumentFragment newNode=xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
newNode.InnerXml=partNnode.OuterXml;
introNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(newNode,introNode);
partNnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(partNnode);
partNnode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//part");
nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//section1");    

foreach (XmlNode refrangeNode in nodeList)
{
    newNode=xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
    newNode.InnerXml=refrangeNode.??OuterXml;
    partNnode.AppendChild(newNode);
}
```

Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post code for what you've attempted so far?

Comment: XmlNode partNnode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//part");          XmlNode introNode=xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//intro"); XmlDocumentFragment newNode=xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();
newNode.InnerXml=partNnode.OuterXml;
introNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(newNode,introNode);
partNnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(partNnode);                partNnode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//part");               nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//section1");   
foreach (XmlNode refrangeNode in nodeList){newNode=xmlDoc.CreateDocumentFragment();newNode.InnerXml=refrangeNode.OuterXml;partNnode.AppendChild(newNode);}

Answer (score 0):

If you load and save a XMl file with C#, then the XML should be formatted correctly (an easy way to format strange looking XML files is just to load and save them with some C# code).

If I understand your question correctly, then you are just not happy with the format of the XML file?

Like you want (A):

```
</intro><part>
```

But you get (B):

```
</intro>
<part>
```

If that is the question, then, in my eyes, you just want a strange thing. Because...

a) Code doesn't care how the XML file is formatted and
b) The format in (B) is the correct one

If you, for what reason ever, want to change it, then you have to parse through the XML file, opening it as a string and checking manually for closed and opened tags.